# find some integer to make an expression an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

suppose K is a fixed integer, P is a fixed prime number, can we always find an integer n to make $\frac{np+1}{k}$ an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need $np+1$  to be divisible by $k$, which means $np\equiv-1 \mod(k)$.

Now, if you let $N = -n$, we have $Np \equiv 1 \mod(k)$.

By Euler's Theorem, there exists a solution $N$ to this equation when $p$ and $k$ are relatively prime.

This solution $N$ is called the multiplicative modular inverse of $p$ modulo $k$.

So, as long as $k$ is not $p$, you have a solution.

Comment: @ Saketh Malyala When ***k = 1***, why can't $\frac{np+1}{k}$ be an integer?

Comment: yeah, k can be 1

Comment: and k cannot be -p ?

Comment: it cannot be -p either. in addition, k cannot be a multiple of p either

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this when $k=p$.

Comment: +1 Nice observation.

Comment: cannot be -p as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Note $\,\exists x\!:\ k\mid px+1\iff \exists x,y\!:\ ky - px = 1\iff \gcd(k,p)=1,\,$ by Bezout

If so then $\,x \equiv -p^{-1}\pmod{\!k},\,$ which is computable by the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242), or by [Gauss's algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) if $\,p\,$ or $\,k\,$ is prime.